# Notification bar hides top part of answer (when using within-page links)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, javascript

When using Stack Overflow sometimes I get the famous orange notification bar. But when the thing appears when I'm reading an answer (linked to with a within-page link), the bar shows on top of the question, thereby hiding the top part of the answer.

To reproduce this behaviour, log out of SO, clear/block your cookies and view [a random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2367653#2367653). The following screenshot has been made using Opera, but I also noticed this when using Firefox:

[image]

When closing the bar, it gets even worse, as the page is scrolled down a little after the orange bar disappears, still hiding the topmost part of the answer:

[image]

(BTW, the hidden line of text reads: “I wish I had invented it myself, but credit goes to Jason Gorman”.)

Is this some kind of intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design

1. the notification bar docks at the top. While it pushes down the TOP of the page, you're at a random-ish scroll point in the middle of the page ..
2. You should *want* to dismiss this by clicking the [x] so we know you've read it (and hopefully the FAQ).

Comment: 1: Ok, I understand this. 2: I know, but upon doing so, the page scrolls back (because the top of the page is no longer pushed down) to a position wherein the first line is no longer readable (see screenshot #2).